# Why Guava StandardTable put method refuse null value

Tags: guava

Guava StandardTable class override AbstractTable's put method

```
// in AbstractTable class
@CanIgnoreReturnValue
@Override
public V put(R rowKey, C columnKey, V value) {
  return row(rowKey).put(columnKey, value);
}

// in StandardTable class
@CanIgnoreReturnValue
@Override
public V put(R rowKey, C columnKey, V value) {
  checkNotNull(rowKey);
  checkNotNull(columnKey);
  checkNotNull(value);
  return getOrCreate(rowKey).put(columnKey, value);
}
```

i create table use

```
Tables.newCustomTable(Maps.newLinkedHashMap(), Maps::newHashMap);
```

my code will set null value into table in some case, but gauva will throw exception in put method, puzzled
how can i implement a standard table with nullable value? (i tried to implement ForwardingTable, override get/put method, use specific class replace null value, but it's not enough, for example: row method will return map contains specific class instead of null)

Comment: Why? Because that's how the designers decided to design it. Null should be avoided in general, since it's a huge source of bugs. Use a special value instead, or change your design, or wrap your values into Optional.

Comment: I considered use a special value instead, but But changes can affect a lot of code, the same is wrap value into Optional

Comment: If it affects such a lot of code, it shows a lack of encapsulation. This table shouldn't be publicly accessible from anywhere, but wrapped into a class.

Comment: yes, agree to. business code, u know, a lot of developer worked on it. so i'll think about it again, and fix this part take some time if necessary. however, so thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`null` in general seen as key or value in any `Collection` or `Map` is seen as a bad decision. The jdk itself has some examples, `ConcurrentHashMap` does *not* allow null keys or values, so does `ConcurrentSkipListMap` and many others.

So does static factory methods added in `java-9`, like `Map::of`. Even `HashMap` that *does* allow a null key and value, so these would both not fail:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("", null);
map.put(null, "");
```

Using any of the new `java-8` method of a `HashMap` will throw a `NullPointerException`:

```
 // value trying to be null
 chm.merge("", null, (k, v) -> k);
```

And the last point is that all `guava` Collections are not null-tolerant, which to me is great decision.